Infinite booting bug in android studio emulator
After "Starting up" state, emulator stops on "Booting..." state. The screen of emulated device is always black during this. Interestingly, this kind of behavior is only on android 14+. Android 13("Tiramisu") + Pixel 6 works fine. But devices like pixel 7 and newer + android 14("UpsideDownCake") and newer are getting stuck on "Booting...". And for some reason I can't change settings of vm heap, ram, and graphics on those devices.
I created devices, deleted them, wiped data. Nothing helped. The max time I waited was 15 mins.

So the problem was that for some reason if I download api 35 image for pixel 8 for example, it didn't automatically download "Android API 35" which you can download in "SDK manager>Languages & Frameworks>Android SDK". Which solved my issue.
